# $1+a+a^{2}+\cdots+a^{\varphi(m)-1}\equiv 0\mod m$

Tags: number-theory

If $\gcd(a,m)=\gcd(a-1,m)=1,$ then $1+a+a^{2}+\cdots+a^{\varphi(m)-1}\equiv 0\mod m.$

I have tried to show that the  elements of the set $\{1,a,a^{2},\cdots,a^{\varphi(m)-1}\}$ are relatively prime with $m$, and then use the following result:

$$\sum_{\gcd(i,m)=1}_{i<m}i=\dfrac{1}{2}m\varphi(m).$$

But it didn't work out, because I found out that it is only true if $\varphi(m)$ is equal the lower power $j$ such that $a^{j}\equiv 1 \mod m.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1) = x^n - 1$

So,

$(1+a+a^2+ \cdots + a^{\varphi(m)-1})(a-1) = a^{\varphi(m)}-1$

but since $\gcd(m,a)=1$ we know that $a^{\varphi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ by Euler's totient function theorem.

therefore: 
$(1+a+a^2+ \cdots + a^{\varphi(m)-1})(a-1) = a^{\varphi(m)}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$

but since $\gcd(m,a-1)=1$ we know that $(a-1)$ is invertible. So, cancelling $a-1$ would give $1+a+\cdots+a^{\varphi(m)-1} \equiv 0 \pmod{0}$

Answer (score 1):

Saying that $\gcd(a-1,m)=1$ means that $a-1$ is invertible modulo $m$, so your equality is equivalent to
$$
(a-1)(1+a+a^{2}+\cdots+a^{\varphi(m)-1})\equiv (a-1)0\pmod{m}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget your high school algebra: you know the sum of that series!